# running php -v on shell there was no output

Tags: php, linux, shell

i have a problem with the php cli. If i execute php -v at the shell, there was no output about the php version.

over /usr/bin/php -v there was no output too.

Version of cli package is php-cli-5.5.4-1.el5.remi.x86_64
and php-5.5.4-1.el5.remi.x86_64

Os = centos-release-5-8.el5.centos

Thx for helping.

Comment: So what do you get? Is there any exit code (check by running 'echo $?' after 'php -v'). What happens if you strace it ('strace php -v')?

Comment: hi alexander, thx for your help. the output of strace php -v is here http://pastebin.com/S4QJa6nD . if i execute php -v echo$ there happens nothing.

Comment: if i try php -n -v its show me the output.

Comment: ok, i found the solution. for all user with the same problem. test if php -n -v get an output. if you get an output then your php.ini config is wrong. My Problem was safe_mode = On. But its deprecated !